# my accesskey control is for the top row in safari and bottom row in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table, access-keys

I have a dynamic editable table with JavaScript, each row has an edit and delete button.
I have given accesskey "`e`" for edit and "`d`" for delete.
In safari <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> selects the first row of the table.
In chrome <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> selects the last row of the table.

I want it to access the first row in chrome as well.

`````
<button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" accesskey="e" onclick="butRowEdit(this);notApplicable();">
<span class="fa fa-pencil" > </span>
</button>
<button id="bElim" type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-outline-secondary" accesskey="d" onclick="butRowDelete(this);remove();">
<span class="fa fa-trash" > </span>
</button>
<button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-outline-secondary" style="display:none;" accesskey="s" onclick="save();butRowAcep(this);">
<span class="fa fa-check" > </span>
</button>
<button id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-outline-secondary" style="display:none;" accesskey="c" onclick="butRowCancel(this);">
<span class="fa fa-times" > </span>
</button>
</div>````
`````

Comment: I have a table which is editable. Each row has it's own edit button, when you click the edit button, the row opens up into textboxes/ select etc. I want to provide an access key , when "e" is pressed, the first row of the table becomes editable. In safari , the first row becomes editable. In chrome the last row becomes editable.

Comment: yes, 11 days ago, I read what you wrote, and you've added absolutely zero new information in that comment.  In my comment I was wondering why you've done it that way - since **you** wrote the code (presumably, no code, so I have no idea if you wrote anything at all) then it's **your** code that behaves this way - perhaps you've written it wrong? Perhaps you don't understand your own code? But, only you can figure out what you've done wrong, since only you can see what you've done wrong.

Comment: I have not created an Accesskey. Maybe you have misread my question. I intend to use Accesskey through html. I never said I "created" an Accesskey.

Comment: Do you have a solution or are you just interested in arguing?

Comment: I've lost all interest since you've shown no code - good luck and good bye